# match regexp against variable string in perl/sed/awk

Tags: regex, linux, perl, awk, sed

I have this expression:

XX h, YY min, ZZ s,

XX, YY or ZZ can be 1 or 2 digits. Also "XX h," or "XX h, YY min," maybe not present. Can anyone recommend any perl or sed expression to extract XX YY and ZZ??

I've tried some matching group regexp with no luck.

thanks

EDIT:

example1: 12 h, 23 min, 2 s,

output1: 12 23 2

example2: 3 min, 59 s,

output2: 3 59

Comment: Can you provide example input and expected output matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "12 h, 3 min, 56 s," | tr -cd "0-9 "
```

Output:

```
12  3  56
```

---

```
echo "12 h, 3 min, 56 s," | tr "," "\n" | awk '/h/ {print $1}'
```

12

```
echo "12 h, 3 min, 56 s," | tr "," "\n" | awk '/min/ {print $1}'
```

3

```
echo "12 h, 3 min, 56 s," | tr "," "\n" | awk '/s/ {print $1}'
```

56

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Perl):

```
my @matches = "1 h, 30 min, 15 s" =~ /(\d{1,2}) [hms]/g;
```

Or a bit stricter

```
my @matches = "1 h, 30 min, 15 s" =~ /(\d{1,2}) (?:h|min|s)/g;

if(scalar @matches == 3) {
    my ($h, $mi, $s) = @matches;
    print "$h : $mi : $s\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about Perl regex. Let's assume you need to be able to extract the following substrings:

```
12 h, 54 min, 11 s,   # you have a trailing comma in your example
1 h, 54 min, 11 s,
54 min, 11 s,
4 min, 11 s,
55 s,
```

and so on. We will need some building blocks:

`\d`: any digit
`?`: when appended to something (a character, a meta-character like `\d` or a group in brackets), make it optional
`( )`: brackets for grouping and extracting values into `$1`, `$2`, etc.
`(?: )`: brackets for grouping without extracting

The seconds part will be `\d\d? s,`.
After adding minutes that can be optional, we'll get `(?:\d\d? min, )?\d\d? s,`.
After adding hours (also optional), we'll get `(?:(?:\d\d? h,)? \d\d? min, )?\d\d? s,`.
Now we'll use brackets around all this staff for capturing the match into `$1` and we'll finally get a regex:

```
/((?:(?:\d\d? h,)? \d\d? min, )?\d\d? s,)/
```

Or, and is the trailing comma also optional? Just add `?` after it.

If you need the values for `h`, `min`, and `s`, put each `\d\d?` into a pair of brackets and check `$2`, `$3` and `$4`:

```
/((?:(?:(\d\d?) h,)? (\d\d?) min, )?(\d\d?) s,)/
```

This is not the easiest possible regex for this task but I just wanted to show how you can build them starting from something very simple and then adding more complex things to it.

Comment: did not work for me with:

`root@pc:~# echo "2 min, 13 s" | perl -pe 's/((?:(?:\d\d? h,)? \d\d? min, )?\d\d? s,)/$1/'

2 min, 13 s`

Comment: Did not work because of the trailing comma (that you had in your example). Remove the last comma from the regex and try :) Also, don't work as root.

Comment: nope :(

`pep@mel2:~# echo "2 min, 13 s" | perl -pe 's/((?:(?:\d\d? h,)? \d\d? min, )?\d\d? s)/$1/'`

**output** --> 2 min, 13 s

Comment: and what output would you expect here, why 2 min 13 s is wrong? It just matches the whole string.

Comment: Then take the last regex from my answer (with groups of digits in their own brackets) and print `$2 $3 $4`.